# Graph drawing from sqlite3 data

Tags: web, graph, sqlite

I'm working with an SQlite3 database over a Debian computer. The information stored inside the database comes from several sensors which are recording temperatura, humidity, etc., so it will be nice to be able to present that data in a graphic way (better curves than bars). Web based, of course, would be awsome.

I'm looking for the best way to do it. All the information related to graph drawing from SQLite referes to Android, but I'm looking for a linux solution.

Anybody?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want us to show you all the code necessary for drawing a graph, or to find a library?

Comment: Find a library, of course!